# SQLiteDatabase.query doesn't replace ?s

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, where-clause

it seems the SQLiteDatabase.query() method doesn't replace my ?s in the where clause with the selectionArgs:

```
String[] columns = new String[] { Table.COL_WEIGHT };
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { Table.COL_DATE, Table.COL_DATE,
        Table.TABLE_NAME };

String sqlquery = SQLiteQueryBuilder.buildQueryString(false, Table.TABLE_NAME,
        columns, "?=(SELECT max(?) FROM ?)", null, null, null, null);

Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(sqlquery, selectionArgs);
```

This thows the following exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException:
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{Activity}:
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "?":
syntax error (code 1): , while compiling:
SELECT Weight FROM Bodyfat WHERE ?=(SELECT max(?) FROM ?)
```

While:

```
String sql = String.format("SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE %s=(SELECT max(%s) FROM %s)",
        Table.COL_WEIGHT, Table.TABLE_NAME, Table.COL_DATE,
        Table.COL_DATE, Table.TABLE_NAME);
//SELECT Weight FROM Bodyfat WHERE Date=(SELECT max(Date) FROM Bodyfat)


Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

Works like expected. Am I using query() and it's selectionArgs correctly?

Comment: **"?"** doesn't work the way you are trying. You must use input parameters in your query too.

Comment: Could you please give an example, Waqas?

Comment: Take a look at the Java tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: consult the Reading module in this article http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: The only difference I see in the androidhive article is that they used query() instead of rawQuery what I already tried:
`Cursor cursor = mDb.query(Table.TABLE_NAME, columns, "?=(SELECT max(?) FROM ?)",
                selectionArgs, null, null, null);`
crashes too.

Comment: It seems that it really is because of passing a tablename as parameter since `Cursor cursor = mDb.query(Table.TABLE_NAME, columns,
                "?=(SELECT max(?) FROM " + Table.TABLE_NAME + ")", selectionArgs, null,
                null, null);` works.